# Where is the "Group" button in Gephi 0.9.2?

Tags: partition, gephi

I am new to Gephi, and am using Gephi 0.9.2. I randomly generated a graph. Then I ran "Modularity" in Statistics. I went to "nodes" and then "partition". According to some online tutorials, there should be a "group" button next to "apply", which allows me to put the nodes into several groups based on their modularity class.

But I cannot find that "group" button. Where is that button? Thank you very much!

Comment: could you point out that tutorial by editing your post?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! You are probably checking tutorials for an *older Gephi version*.

If I'm not wrong, in `Gephi 0.9.2` the corresponding option, has been moved under menu **Tools>Generate groups by partition**, like it is shown below.

[image]

If this was not what you are looking for, try to edit your question, giving us a link to the tutorial you were looking at.